# AWS CDK - Get userdata commands within Aspect

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm writing an [Aspect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/aspects.html) to update `UserData` in a `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` or `AWS::EC2::Instance`.

```py
@jsii.implements(IAspect)
class CfnInitAspect:

    resource_types = [
        "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
        "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    ]
    def visit(self, node: IConstruct):
        if (
            CfnResource.is_cfn_resource(node)
            and node.cfn_resource_type in self.resource_types
        ): 
            user_data = node.user_data
```

If I do a `print(user_data)` it resolves to `${Token[TOKEN.185]}`.

When I run a `cdk synth`, the userdata resolves fine to

```json
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": {
    "Fn::Join": [
      "",
      [
        "#!/bin/bash\n# fingerprint: a27a60dbefd60e38\n(\n  set +e\n  /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --region ",
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::Region"
        },
        " --stack ",
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
        },
        " --resource someserviceASG4BD2CED0 -c default\n  /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --region ",
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::Region"
        },
        " --stack ",
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
        },
        " --resource someserviceASG4BD2CED0\n  cat /var/log/cfn-init.log >&2\n)"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to use an Aspect to alter the list in side the userdata, but can't seem to resolve the values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this in the following way

```py
from monocdk import (
    IAspect,
    IConstruct,
    CfnResource,
    Stack,
)
import jsii

@jsii.implements(IAspect)
class CfnInitAspect:

    resource_types = [
        "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
        "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    ]
    def visit(self, node: IConstruct):
        if (
            CfnResource.is_cfn_resource(node)
            and node.cfn_resource_type in self.resource_types
        ): 
            userdata = Stack.of(node).resolve(node.user_data)
```